# Help! Do i need to approve the application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to implemend in app purchase in my application.

when i run the application on the device, i get invalid product identifiers as response.

I have added the application to in app purchase , and made it to cleared for sale.

And the status is " Pending developer approval"

But i did not approve the application still...

Do i need to approve the the application to fix the invalid product identifiers error....

am i missing any point here..

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an "In-App Purchase Test User" on iTunes Connect, and use it for testing your in-app purchase.

Comment: @tia: Hi..thanks for the reply..yes i have created test user on iTunes connect. when we ill be using that test account on the device.pls guide me out...i am not sure when i need to use those test account.jus to get the product information do i need test account on my device.

Comment: Sorry I got the situation wrong at the first place. Have you checked your bundle identifier in your plist?

Comment: @tia: yes those are same yar. do i need to approve and submit a binary to get valid product identifiers

Comment: No, but If I remember correctly I think you need to wait for few days and your IDs will be approved for development. You don't need to approve or submit any binary for testing in-app. I'll ask my colleague and tell you later because I am testing in-app but he's the one who did the setup.

Comment: @tia: can you pls provide me some help

Comment: I have asked my colleague and he said you need to approve the product ids by yourself. I think there must be somewhere on the iTunes connect to click to approve those ids for testing only.